# Sections with custom numbering

Tags: sectioning, numbering

Can I have

```
Para numbers     as 1.
sub para         as     (a)
sub sub para     as          (i)
sub sub sub para as               (aa)
```

Comment: Does "para" refer to a `\paragraph` or a `\section`? There is a big difference. Also, what would the next value for `(aa)`enumerate to... `(bb)`?

Comment: Two questions: First, how important is the indentation of the lower-ranking sectioning "numbers"? Second, do you plan to cross-reference any of these sectioning items? If so, how should the cross-referenced items look like? E.g., should they feature the surrounding parentheses, or should they be rendered (say) as `1.a.i.aa`?

Comment: there is a big chance to have multiples (a) multiples (i) multiples (aa) this way. that's why usually we use 1.a and 2.a.i

Comment: Assuming the lower-level sectioning headers should be indented, does this imply that the associated text should be indented as well? Please advise.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a way if `para` means `\section` etc. (In this case, `\thesection` does not need to be changed).

The `(aa)` numbering can be obtained by `\alphalph` and increasing the `subparagraph` number by `26` only virtually.

I've provided a `enumitem` way in case a list is actually meant.

In case of the `\section` - version -- I don't recommend this numbering/labelling style at all!

The question is also: Is the first `a` of `(aa)` the label coming from `paragraph` (a)`? Or is it always`(aa)`, regardless which numbering the higher level has?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\usepackage{alphalph}

\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{(\alph{section})}
\renewcommand{\thesubsubsection}{(\roman{subsubsection})}
\renewcommand{\theparagraph}{(\alphalph{\numexpr\value{paragraph}+26})}
\renewcommand{\thesubparagraph}{(\alphalph{\numexpr\value{paragraph}}\alphalph{\numexpr\value{subparagraph}+26})}


\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}


\makeatletter
\def\aaitem#1{\expandafter\@aaitem\csname c@#1\endcsname}
\def\@aaitem#1{%
  \alphalph{\the\numexpr#1+26}%
}
\AddEnumerateCounter*{\aaitem}{\@aaitem}{100}


\makeatother

\newlist{paralist}{enumerate}{4}
\setlist[paralist]{font={\bfseries}}
\setlist[paralist,1]{label={\arabic*}}
\setlist[paralist,2]{label={(\roman*)}}
\setlist[paralist,3]{label={(\alph*)}}
\setlist[paralist,4]{label={(\aaitem*)}}



\begin{document}

\begin{paralist}
\item Foo
  \begin{paralist}
  \item Foo Bar
    \begin{paralist}
    \item Foo Bar Foo
      \begin{paralist}
      \item Foo Bar Foo Bar
      \item Foo Bar Foo Bar Foo
      \end{paralist}
    \item Foo Bar Foo
    \end{paralist}
  \item Foo Bar 
  \end{paralist}
\item Foo
\end{paralist}


\section{Foo}
\subsection{Foobar}
\subsubsection{FooBarFoo}
\paragraph{FooBarFooBar}
\paragraph{More FooBarFooBar}

\subsubsection{Other FooBarFoo}

\paragraph{FooBarFooBarFoo}

\paragraph{Even More FooBarFooBarFoo}

\subparagraph{FooBarFooBarFoo}




\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I have a feeling that the custom enumerated list approach is the way to go, as it automatically indents not only the enumerated "numbers" but also any associated text.

Comment: @Mico: I agree -- actually it was my first idea before trying with the `\section` way